# Open in local browser URL from remote SSH computer

Tags: terminal, network, ssh, remote-desktop, tunnel

Situation is like this:

1. From my home I connect over SSH to remote router with static IP.

   ```
    ssh routeruser@static_router_ip
   ```
2. Than from router console over SSH, I connect to mac-mini.

   ```
    ssh macuser@local_macmini_ip
   ```

How to open URL from remote macmini, in my local browser?

Comment: Opening URLs and screen sharing seem to be two different things, what exactly do you want to accomplish here? Also, I assume both computers are Macs?

Comment: Both computers are Mac. I was thinking, maybe it is easier to connect to remote mac over screenshare (remote-desktop) and open URL directly in remote browser. But the main question is to open URL from remote macmini, in my local browser.

Comment: So you are running a webserver on the remote Mac, and want to access some pages stored on the remote? Can you configure your router to forward a port to port 80 on the remote?